# CSS motion path onClick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with my CSS and javascript code which I have uploaded to [codepen](https://codepen.io/karsten-dall-s-rensen/pen/wvWvJgK).

I am trying to use CSS motion path, I would like to be able to control this with JavaScript, so when you press the "Forward button" it runs to the last keyframe and that works, But when I press the "Back button" then nothing happens.  I will like it to move back to the first keyframe.

The question if I am on the right track with my code? and what I need to change?

```js
function myForwardFunction() {
  document.getElementById("pathed").style.animationPlayState = "running";
}

function myBackFunction() {
  document.getElementById("pathed").style.animationDirection = "reverse";
}
```

```css
section {
  width: 244px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px dashed lightgrey;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid hsl(343, 100%, 58%, .3);
  border-right: 5px solid hsl(343, 100%, 58%);
  background: hsla(343, 100%, 58%, .3) radial-gradient(circle, hsl(343, 100%, 58%, 1) 3px, hsl(343, 100%, 58%, 0) 3px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
}

.pathed {
  offset-path: path('M0,0 C40,240 200,240 240,0');
  position: absolute;
  animation: distance 4000ms alternate ease-in-out;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

@keyframes distance {
  from {
    offset-distance: 0%;
  }
  to {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}

code {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

section {
  position: relative;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .333;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myForwardFunction()">Forward</button>

<button onclick="myBackFunction()">Back</button>


<section>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 240 200"><path d="M0,0 C40,240 200,240 240,0" fill="none" stroke="lightgrey"/></svg>
  <div id="pathed" class="pathed"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: I think you've forgotten to post your codepen

Comment: https://codepen.io/karsten-dall-s-rensen/pen/wvWvJgK

Comment: any error in the console ?

Comment: no Error in the console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

**Updated**

**css**

```
.pathed {
  offset-path: path('M0,0 C40,240 200,240 240,0');
  position: absolute;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-direction: normal;

}
@keyframes distance_1 {
  from {
    offset-distance: 0%;
  }
  to{  offset-distance: 100%;}
}

@keyframes distance_2 {
  from {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
  to{  offset-distance: 0%;}
}
```

**js**

```
 function myForwardFunction() {
      document.getElementById("pathed").style.animation = "distance_1 4000ms alternate ease-in-out";
      document.getElementById("pathed").style.animationDirection = "running";
      document.getElementById("pathed").style.animationFillMode = "forwards";
    }

    function myBackFunction() {
      document.getElementById("pathed").style.animation = "distance_2 4000ms alternate ease-in-out";
      document.getElementById("pathed").style.animationDirection = "running";
      document.getElementById("pathed").style.animationFillMode = "backwards";
    }
```

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/0cr78g93/)

Comment: Janitha Rasanga, thank you so much for your help i really appreciate it

Answer (score 5):

You may also toggle a `class` and use a `transition`:

```js
function myForwardFunction() {
  document.getElementById("pathed").classList.add('to100');
}
function myBackFunction() {
  document.getElementById("pathed").classList.toggle('to100');
}
```

```css
section {
  width: 244px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px dashed lightgrey;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid hsl(343, 100%, 58%, .3);
  border-right: 5px solid hsl(343, 100%, 58%);
  background: hsla(343, 100%, 58%, .3) radial-gradient(circle, hsl(343, 100%, 58%, 1) 3px, hsl(343, 100%, 58%, 0) 3px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
}

.pathed {
  offset-path: path('M0,0 C40,240 200,240 240,0');
  position: absolute;
  transition: 4s;
  offset-distance: 0%;
}

.pathed.to100 {
  offset-distance: 100%;
}

code {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

section {
  position: relative;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .333;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
small {font-size:0.6em}
```

```html
<button onclick="myForwardFunction()">Forward</button>
<button onclick="myBackFunction()">Back<small>/toggle direction</small></button>


<section>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 240 200"><path d="M0,0 C40,240 200,240 240,0" fill="none" stroke="lightgrey"/></svg>
  <div id="pathed" class="pathed"></div>
</section>
```

**edit** as suggested by @wizzwizz4 comment , you can use your js to set the onclick function on your button:

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('#click');
let div = document.querySelector('#pathed');
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle('to100');
  div.classList.toggle('to100');
});
```

```css
section {
  width: 244px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px dashed lightgrey;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid hsl(343, 100%, 58%, .3);
  border-right: 5px solid hsl(343, 100%, 58%);
  background: hsla(343, 100%, 58%, .3) radial-gradient(circle, hsl(343, 100%, 58%, 1) 3px, hsl(343, 100%, 58%, 0) 3px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
}

.pathed {
  offset-path: path('M0,0 C40,240 200,240 240,0');
  position: absolute;
  transition: 4s;
  offset-distance: 0%;
}

.pathed.to100 {
  offset-distance: 100%;
}

#click:after {
  content: ' forwards';
}

#click.to100:after {
  content: ' backwards';
}

code {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

section {
  position: relative;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .333;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

small {
  font-size: 0.6em
}
```

```html
<button id=click>Click to go</button>


<section>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 240 200"><path d="M0,0 C40,240 200,240 240,0" fill="none" stroke="lightgrey"/></svg>
  <div id="pathed" class="pathed"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi G-Cyrillus, thank you so much for your help i really appreciate it

Comment: @user10238568 That's what upvotes are for. ☺ Remember to accept one of these answers when one of them has solved the problem.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, would it be better to use `addEventListener` instead of the `onclick` attribute?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 yes, it would keep html cleaner, also a single button is enough to toggle the class . mybackFunction() does the job on itself ;)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 added a snippet with the `addEventListener` and a single button ;)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because by default css animation only play for one time. This can be controlled by `animation-iteration-count` property, and its initial value is set to 1 by default.

So even when you reverse the animation direction by pressing "back" button, the animation has already been played one time, so it's ended. Thus you see no effect.

For your use case you need to reset the internal state of css animation. This can be done by setting `element.style.animation = 'none'` then unset it `element.style.animation = ''`. But there's a trick here, you cannot simply write JS like:

```js
element.style.animation = 'none';
element.style.animation = '';
```

This will not work. According to https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/, you have two options to cast the magic spell.

1. `setTimeout()`

```js
element.style.animation = 'none';
setTimeout(() => {
  element.style.animation = '';
})
```

2. `void pathed.offsetWidth;`

```js
element.style.animation = 'none';
// magic: accessing `.offsetWidth` triggers a reflow
void pathed.offsetWidth;
element.style.animation = '';
```

I like the second option cus it looks more elegant. So you just need to change your JS to:

```js
const pathed = document.getElementById("pathed");

function myForwardFunction() {
  pathed.style.animation = 'none';
  void pathed.offsetWidth;
  pathed.style.animation = '';
  pathed.style.animationDirection = "normal";
  pathed.style.animationPlayState = "running";
}

function myBackFunction() {
  pathed.style.animation = 'none';
  void pathed.offsetWidth;
  pathed.style.animation = '';
  pathed.style.animationDirection = "reverse";
  pathed.style.animationPlayState = "running";
}
```

Expand to see full solution:

```js
const pathed = document.getElementById("pathed");
function myForwardFunction() {
  pathed.style.animation = 'none';
  void pathed.offsetWidth;
  pathed.style.animation = '';
  pathed.style.animationDirection = "normal";
  pathed.style.animationPlayState = "running";
}

function myBackFunction() {
  pathed.style.animation = 'none';
  void pathed.offsetWidth;
  pathed.style.animation = '';
  pathed.style.animationDirection = "reverse";
  pathed.style.animationPlayState = "running";
}
```

```css
section {
  width: 244px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px dashed lightgrey;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid hsl(343, 100%, 58%, .3);
  border-right: 5px solid hsl(343, 100%, 58%);
  background: hsla(343, 100%, 58%, .3) radial-gradient(circle, hsl(343, 100%, 58%, 1) 3px, hsl(343, 100%, 58%, 0) 3px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
}

.pathed {
  offset-path: path('M0,0 C40,240 200,240 240,0');
  position: absolute;
  animation: distance 1000ms alternate ease-in-out;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

@keyframes distance {
  from {
    offset-distance: 0%;
  }
  to {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}

code {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

section {
  position: relative;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .333;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myForwardFunction()">Forward</button>

<button onclick="myBackFunction()">Back</button>


<section>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 240 200"><path d="M0,0 C40,240 200,240 240,0" fill="none" stroke="lightgrey"/></svg>
  <div id="pathed" class="pathed"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi hackape thank you so much for your help i really appreciate it

Comment: Hi all
I could use all your answers equally well but had to choose a solution, and accept one of these answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [G-cyrillus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64279042/13331155)'s answer but using pure CSS:

```css
input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

label {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  left: -170px;
  top: 80px;
}

section {
  width: 244px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px dashed lightgrey;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid hsl(343, 100%, 58%, .3);
  border-right: 5px solid hsl(343, 100%, 58%);
  background: hsla(343, 100%, 58%, .3) radial-gradient(circle, hsl(343, 100%, 58%, 1) 3px, hsl(343, 100%, 58%, 0) 3px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
}

.pathed {
  offset-path: path('M0,0 C40,240 200,240 240,0');
  position: absolute;
  transition: 4s;
}

#back:checked ~ .pathed {
  offset-distance: 0%;
}

#forward:checked ~ .pathed {
  offset-distance: 100%;
}

section {
  position: relative;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .333;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  left: 0;
  top: 17px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <input type="radio" id="forward" name="toggle">
  <label for="forward">Forwards</label>

  <input type="radio" id="back" name="toggle">
  <label for="back">Back</label>
  
  <svg viewBox="0 0 240 200"><path d="M0,0 C40,240 200,240 240,0" fill="none" stroke="lightgrey"/></svg>
  <div id="pathed" class="pathed"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: cool use of radio/label elements indeed - page is js free . weird in the same time .. I've used to program events like this in js,, debugging in future could be issue alos ..